# Replicate position_fill calculations

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is possibly more of a maths question than a coding one, but this has me really stuck! I have a data frame in the format of this small reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(sample = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3 , 3), rep(4 , 3)),
                 condition = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6)),
                 amino_acid = rep(c("Asx", "Glx", "Ser"), 4),
                 conc = c(2, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1, 8, 2, 5), 
                 total_conc = c(rep(9, 3), rep(12, 3), rep(4 , 3), rep(15 , 3))) %>% 
     mutate(pc_conc = conc / total_conc * 100)
```

I want to look at the change in the proportion of amino_acid concs (i.e. change in pc_conc) with the conditions a and b, which I can do using `fun.y = "mean"` and `position = position_fill()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = condition, y = pc_conc, fill = amino_acid)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", na.rm = TRUE,
  position = position_fill())
```

[image: ggplot of average pc_conc for each condition using position_fill()]

What I want is the values of each of these bars (i.e. the average proportion of `conc` for each `amino_acid` for each `condition`). If I average `pc_conc` in the original dataframe you can see that I don't get the same result:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(condition, amino_acid) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(pc_conc), mean)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = condition, y = pc_conc, fill = amino_acid)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "identity", na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image: ggplot of average pc_conc for each condition, averages calculated before plotting]

How can I either extract the values calculated by the position_fill() function from the ggplot object or replicate those calculations so I have the same numbers? I've tried averaging the original conc and total_conc variables and calculating pc_conc but that also doesn't create the normalised percentages I'm looking for.

Comment: You can get this data with `layer_data(my_plot)` which I strangely can't  pipe. Try `ggplot_build` too.

Comment: You can get them like this: `layer_data(my_plot)[c("ymin","ymax","xmin","xmax","x","y")]`.

Comment: @NelsonGon Thank you, I have the data now - is there a way to collect it with the factor names preserved? My actual data set is much larger and it would take a long time to match up the values manually.

Comment: If you just call `layer_data(my_plot)` without anything else, you will have everything with the factor names preserved. You can find them under "group".

Comment: @NelsonGon Doing this doesn't preserve the factor names, only giving a list of numbers. Is there a quick way I can add the names back in?

Comment: You can replace them by matching them to the original values(levels). The numbers are just the levels?

Comment: @NelsonGon The numbers in group don't match up with either the x factor levels or the y factor levels. I think there's a different number for every unique combination of x and y factor levels. So do I have to make a new df coding each number to the x + y factor combination, match them to the group values, then split that column?

Comment: Sorry, it's relatively late in the evening right now where I am. Will look at it later if someone else doesn't.

Comment: Not sure but if you have just one grouping, isn't this sufficient? `cbind(layer_data(my_plot)["group"], df$group)`. Compare and see if this works for you.